# How to get a Mirror in Swift without creating an instance?

Tags: swift, reflection

In Swift 2.0, we can use `Mirror(reflecting:)` to get some type information from an instance, e.g.

```
let stringMirror = Mirror(reflecting: "a string")
print(stringMirror.children)
```

However, is it possible to get information about a type *without* creating an instance? (For those of you who may want to know why I want this: The question is purely academic. Can it be done?)

My guess is no, because I think `Mirror` is intended for use by playgrounds and is not an "official" reflection API.

Comment: did you ever find a work around? Maybe using a different tool? I have a requirement where I need to list out the properties' name and type, (not the values) of enums, structs, or classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> Mirror: Representation of the sub-structure and optional "display style" of any arbitrary **subject instance**.

So I believe the answer to your question is "No".