# Swift - Return type of struct parameters without default values

Tags: swift

I'm very new in Swift so i might be missing some basics.

I have struct:

```
    struct MyStruct {
        var a: Int
        var b: String
        var c: Bool
        
        init() {
          a: Int = 1,
          b: String? = "",
          c: Bool? = false
        }
    }
```

and function, that should iterate through given struct properties and return their types in json:

```
func structProps(){
  let elm = MyStruct()
  let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: elm)
  var exampleDict: [String: String] = [:]
  for child in mirror.children  {
      exampleDict[child.label!] = String(describing:type(of: child.value)) as String
  }
  if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: exampleDict,
      options: []) {
      let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .ascii)
  }
}
```

it kinda return what i need:

```
JSON string = {"a":"Int","b":"String","c":"Bool"}
```

Because i'm having a lot of structs and i want to export json from all of them, i'm wondering if there is a way to have **generic initializer**. Without passing default values.

It means without

```
init() {
 a: Int = 1,
 b: String? = "",
 c: Bool? = false
}
```

Comment: Regarding having a generic initialiser, I don't really understand what you mean here? How are you going to give your objects any values with such an initialiser?

Comment: Unrelated but an init method with optional parameter types which are forced unwrapped immediately is pointless.

Comment: The output that i'm expecting is actually what i have now. But i must specify a: Int = 1, b: String? = "", c: Bool? = false. I would like to remove init() from struct, but in my function i cannot use let elm = MyStruct() without parameters

Comment: Ok, I see now that I did misread the question. You do not want to export objects but the definition of your structs. Sorry. I am not sure if that is doable in swift since the language doesn't have very good support for reflection

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. Other developers will create structs without default values as they will be passed in functions elsewhere. I just need to get them (with or without init params) and return only types.

Comment: So do you think i have to have init params for that or convert struct to dictionary?

Comment: Maybe there is some tool/library that could analyse source code and extract this kind of meta data but that feels like a different topic. I don't think there is any general solution here so I would add an init or static method in an extension to each struct that uses default values and use this in your current code.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that, thanks @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Creating a Swift Runtime Library](https://medium.com/@weswickwire/creating-a-swift-runtime-library-3cc92fc486cc), there is a way to access meta data types without initializer.
Solution for what i was asking for is possible with [Runtime](https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime) library.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly , you can create a base protocol and add as an extension to your structures like

```
protocol BaseFunction {
    func getElements() -> [String : String]
    func getDict() -> String
}

extension BaseFunction { 
  func getElements() -> [String : String] {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let propertiesRemoveNil = mirror.children.filter({!(($0.value as AnyObject) is NSNull)})
    let properties = propertiesRemoveNil.compactMap({$0.label})
    
    var types = [String]()
    _ = mirror.children.forEach({
        types.append(String(describing:type(of: $0.value)))
    })
    
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(properties, types))
    
  }
    func getDict() -> String{
    if let theJSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(
      withJSONObject: getElements(),
      options: []) {
        
        let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData, encoding: .ascii)
        return theJSONText ?? ""
        
    }
    return ""
  }

}
```

And usage :

```
func structProps(){
    let elm = MyStruct()
    print(elm.getDict())
    
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
{"a":"Int","b":"String","c":"Bool"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a comment about using a protocol but I thought it would be easier to understand as an answer with some code.

To make the usage more generic so you don't need specific code for each type of struct you should use a protocol. Instead of having an `init` that might clash with already existing init in the struct I prefer a static method that returns a new object, also known as a factory method

```
protocol PropertyExtract {
    static func createEmpty() -> PropertyExtract
}
```

Then we can make use of the default init for the struct or any supplied to create an object with some initial values by letting the struct conform to the protocol in an extension

```
extension MyStruct: PropertyExtract {
    static func createEmpty() -> PropertyExtract {
        MyStruct(a: 0, b: "", c: false)
    }
}
```

And instead of hardcoding or passing a specific type of object to the encoding function we pass the type of it

```
func structProps(for structType: PropertyExtract.Type)
```

and use the protocol method to get an instance of the type

```
let object = structType.createEmpty()
```

The whole function (with some additional changes)

```
func structProps(for structType: PropertyExtract.Type) -> String? {
    let object = structType.createEmpty()
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)

    let exampleDict = mirror.children.reduce(into: [String:String]()) {
        guard let label = $1.label else { return }
        $0[label] = String(describing:type(of: $1.value))
    }

    if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(exampleDict) {
         return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    return nil
}
```

And this is then called with the type of the struct

```
let jsonString = structProps(for: MyStruct.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mirror(reflecting:)` expects an instance of a type and not a type itself, [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776699/how-to-get-a-mirror-in-swift-without-creating-an-instance).
One idea is to have a generic function that works with all types conforming to a protocol that provides an empty init. Something like:

```swift
protocol EmptyInitializable {
  init()
}

struct StructOne {
  let a: Bool
  let b: String
}

struct StructTwo {
  let c: Int
  let d: Float
}

extension StructOne: EmptyInitializable {
  init() {
    a = false
    b = ""
  }
}

extension StructTwo: EmptyInitializable {
  init() {
    c = 1
    d = 1.0
  }
}

func print(subject: EmptyInitializable) -> String? {
  let dictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
    Mirror(reflecting: subject).children.map {
      ($0.label!, String(describing: type(of: $0.value)))
    }
  )
  return (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)).flatMap {
    String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8)
  }
}

print(subject: StructOne()) // "{"a":"Bool","b":"String"}"
print(subject: StructTwo()) // "{"d":"Float","c":"Int"}"
```

You still have to implement the empty init and assign some values and I'm afraid there's no way currently to avoid that.